# How to prevent XeLaTeX from dynamically enlarging or shrinking space after comma?

Tags: spacing, xetex, programming, xecjk

See the following output.

[image]

## Question

How to

- prevent XeLaTeX from dynamically enlarging or shrinking space after comma?
- force XeLaTeX to break long sentences automatically without having to consider the hyphenation rule?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper,hmargin=25mm,vmargin=15mm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}


\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}

\renewcommand\rubysep{0pt}
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.4}


\begin{document}
\chapter{睡眠}

あなたは毎晩よく\ruby{寝}{ね}られますか。

調査によると、夜なかなか\ruby{寝}{ね}られなかったり、何回もめが\ruby{覚}{さ}めたりして、医者に相談する人が多くなっているそうです。

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you going to write Japanese all the way? Because `xeCJK` is more suitable for Chinese and there are other solutions for Japanese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first question, write `\usepackage[PunctStyle=plain]{xeCJK}` instead. For second question, write `\pretolerance=10000`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper,hmargin=25mm,vmargin=15mm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[PunctStyle=plain]{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\pretolerance=10000

%\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}

\renewcommand\rubysep{0pt}
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.4}


\begin{document}
\chapter{睡眠}

あなたは毎晩よく\ruby{寝}{ね}られますか。

調査によると、夜なかなか\ruby{寝}{ね}られなかったり、何回もめが\ruby{覚}{さ}めたりして、医者に相談する人が多くなっているそうです。

Sleeping Sleeping Sleeping Sleeping

\pretolerance=-1

Sleeping Sleeping Sleeping Sleeping

\end{document}
```